# create an slider in phpBB header

Tags: html, css, slider, phpbb

I need to create an slider in phpBB header. I have placed the code under 
template/overall_header.html.

But nothing happening. I'm new in phpBB. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the actual overall_header.html file located on the server and not use the editor in your ACP. If you did this already, clear your boards cache which can be found in the ACP 'General' tab. This will force any changes to the template files to be shown.

Comment: Thanks For Your answwer. But I figured it out before 2 days.

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it sorted. If my answer is what you did to solve the problem can you accept the answer so it will help others with the same problem in the future please :)